# why my js is not loaded on postback?

Tags: asp.net

I have a drop down list which is enhanced trough some js script. This DropDownList is inside an UpdatePanel like this:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upStoreDetails" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="dropRestaurants" runat="server" CssClass="styleCB" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTenant_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <uc:popuptenantdescription id="popupTenantDescriptionControl" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I've already register the script for it:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loadJs();
}

private void loadJs()
{
    Type cstype = this.GetType();
    String scriptName = "cufon-yui";

   if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered(cstype, scriptName))
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.Page.GetType(), scriptName, VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/js/cufon-yui.js"));
   }
}
```

which is succesfully inserted when the page is loaded first.

But, on postback (selectedIndexChanged event of `asp:dropDownList`) the style applied to the drop list is lost... Do you see any reason why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my case:

- basically, the src file containes some jQuery methods which were triggered on document ready.

But just registering this script (as I did above) did not also make call to those methods but only included that js file.

So I had to manually call those when doc. ready and IsPostBack, for my case:

```
private void loadJs()
{
    Type cstype = this.GetType();
    String csname = "applyStyleToDropDownList";
    if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(cstype, csname))
    {
        StringBuilder cstext2 = new StringBuilder();
        cstext2.Append("$(function(){ $('.styleCB').customStyle();})");
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), csname, cstext2.ToString(), true);
    }
}
```

Maybe it's useful for others too.